# How do I prevent duplicates from a SQL join?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following tables:

`customer`:

| id | customer_number | company | firstname | lastname | account_manager_email | email | comments | terms | tax_id_number | lead_source | default_catalog | credit_limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99453 | C00123456 | Serenity Inc. | Malcom | Reynolds | jim.smith@example.com | mal@example.com | The cap'n | 1 | NULL | NULL | 12345 | NULL |
| 99468 | C00123456 | Serenity Inc. | Zoe | Washburne | jim.smith@example.com | zoe@example.com | NULL | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 99960 | C00123456 | Serenity Inc. | Hoban | Washburne | jim.smith@example.com | wash@example.com | NULL | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 100088 | C00123456 | Serenity Inc. | Inara | Serra | jim.smith@example.com | inara@example.com | NULL | 1 | NULL | NULL | 12345 | NULL |

`customer_address`:

| id | company | street | city | state_abbreviation | postcode | telephone | firstname | lastname | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 133996 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | Malcom | Reynolds | 2017-05-08 12:45:53.000 |
| 134452 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | Accounts | Payable | 2017-05-09 10:19:59.000 |
| 134961 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | REF | 987654321 | 2017-05-09 10:19:59.000 |
| 134962 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | REF | 192837465 | 2017-05-09 10:19:59.000 |
| 133995 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | Accounts | Payable | 2017-05-09 10:19:59.000 |
| 133669 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | REF | 123456789 | 2017-05-18 10:29:42.000 |
| 133667 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | Accounts | Payable | 2017-05-18 07:56:45.000 |
| 133666 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | Accounts | Payable | 2017-05-31 07:56:46.000 |
| 133626 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | Accounts | Payable | 2017-06-16 12:45:08.000 |
| 133668 | Serenity, Inc | 123 Any St. | Anytown | AX | 12345 | 123-456-7890 | REF | PO | 2017-06-16 12:45:08.000 |

I'm running this query to generate a CSV that I can use to import the data into another system:

```
     SELECT '"' + CAST(c.customer_number AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Customer Number',
            '"' + CAST(c.company AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Company Name',
            '"' + CAST(a.street AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Company Address Line 1',
            '"' + CAST(a.city AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Company City',
            '"' + CAST(a.state_abbreviation AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Company State',
            '"' + CAST(a.postcode AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Company Zip Code',
            '"' + CAST(a.telephone AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Company Phone',
            '"' + CAST(c.firstname AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact First Name',
            '"' + CAST(c.lastname AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact Last Name',
            '"' + CAST(c.account_manager_email AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Account Manager Email',
            '"' + CAST(a.company AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact Company Name',
            '"' + CAST(a.street AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact Address Line 1',
            '"' + CAST(a.city AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact City',
            '"' + CAST(a.state_abbreviation AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact State',
            '"' + CAST(a.postcode AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact Zip Code',
            '"' + CAST(a.telephone AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact Phone',
            '"' + CAST(c.email AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Contact Email',
            '"' + CAST(c.comments AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Internal Notes',
            '"' + CAST(c.terms AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Terms',
            '"' + CAST(c.tax_id_number AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Tax ID (US)',
            '"' + CAST(c.lead_source AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Lead Source',
            '"' + CAST(c.default_catalog AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Catalog',
            '"' + CAST(c.credit_limit AS VARCHAR) + '"' AS 'Credit Limit'
       FROM customer c,
            customer_address a
      WHERE c.customer_number = 'C00123456'
        AND a.company = c.company
   ORDER BY c.customer_number,
            c.created_at;
```

However, when I run that query I get 40 rows back, ten for each entry in `customer`.  I've tried different join types but the results are the same.

A lot of this is legacy data and so the only thing that I appear to reliably be able to join on is the company name ("Serenity, Inc.")

I actually need two versions of this output.  The first is a single row for each company containing the entry with the oldest `created_at` value from the `customer` table.  The second are all the other records.

**Note:** This is on SQL Server 2005 (I know... an upgrade is planned but I have to get through this first)

Comment: Are you sure you cannot reliably join on fristname and lastname? i had answered saying those two columns looks like it is causing your duplication but now im curious as to why you cannot use those two columns?  And if you cannot reliably use them, youre going to have to get creative with massaging in steps to figure out how to do this properly. Im also assuming you dont need the records that are for "accounts payable?"

Comment: You have 4 rows joining to 10 rows in matching values, so of course 4x10=40. Your `Customers` table does not have a `created_at`, that's in your `customers_address`. If you want only a single row, presumably it's the minumum customer `Id`?

Comment: What other joins did you try exactly?

It might be worth learning SQL basics, for example at the following site: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: `customer_address` should have a `customer_id` column that is a foreign key relating each `customer_address` to a `customer`.  Why does it not?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I agree and wish I had the answer to that question but, unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: There might be a linking table.

Comment: The design as shown is flawed, you have no way of uniquely identifying an address for a customer. Also you're using an old style implicit join which are no longer best practice. Your logic becomes much clearer when you use an explicit join.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the [created_at] field is in your [customer_address] table, not the [customer] table, so your example statement with "ORDER BY c.customer_number, c.created_at" would throw an error and cannot be what you were actually testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove your duplicates you need to enumerate each row and assign a value based on an ordering criteria.

You could do this easily using a `cte` - I believe they are available in SQL Server 2005, I am of course unable to check.

```
with c as(
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by customer_number order by id) rn
  from customer
),
ca as (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by company order by created_at) rn
  from customer_address
)
select <columns>
from c join ca on c.company=ca.company
where c.rn=1 and ca.rn=1 and c.customer_number='C00123456'
```

Answer (score -1):

What other joins did you try exactly?

Here's one way of selecting the most recent customer_address record for each customer record:

```
SELECT c.*, a.* FROM
customer c
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT x.* FROM customer_address x
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT company, MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM customer_address 
       GROUP BY company) u
    ON u.company=x.company AND u.created_at=x.created_at
  ) a
ON a.company=c.company
WHERE c.customer_number = 'C00123456';
```

and all the other customer_address records would therefore be given by:

```
  ( SELECT x.* FROM customer_address x
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT company, MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM customer_address 
       GROUP BY company) u
    ON u.company=x.company AND NOT u.created_at=x.created_at
  ) a
```